# How to Download TFS Change History from one tree and Merge it up to another in TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs, history, branching-and-merging

So, I had to re-order files in the repository and as a result, I lost the connection to old history for the set of files. What I would like to do is find someway to hook the old history back up with the stream. How can I accomplish this in TFS or with code?

The steps I took when implementing my branching strategy here

---

1. Created **PRODUCTION/UAT/DEVELOPMENT** folders under the Top directory followed by a Check-in
2. Then created another folder called **INITIALRELEASE** under the PRODUCTION directory, followed by a Check-in
3. TFS moved code files and their containers to **PRODUCTION\INITIALRELEASE folder**, followed up with a Check-in
4. Converted **PRODUCTION\INITIALRELEASE folder** into a Branch
5. From **PRODUCTION\INITIALRELEASE Branch**, I created a child branch called Release_1.0

Comment: Exactly how did you "re-order" the files? Renames shouldn't lose connection to old history.

Comment: Moved the files from one location to another, and then branched

Comment: The history should still be there. When you do "View History" in the new location, are you sure you don't see any lines with a ">" icon next to them?

Comment: No, I don't see that at all.

Comment: I would like to connect the two history logs so that we can still trace back to the old file/folder tree

Comment: I don't know what you did wrong. I've never seen this happen. For me, all the history has always been kept, including when I move files. That's just a "Rename" operation. Does it work for you in cases where you have branches but did not rename or move?

Comment: The project I'm looking at now has just merged, but it doesn't have renames or moves as far as I know. In this case, when I look at the history for a file in the "furthest" branch, it has a little "right-facing triangle" next to it. When I click that, it expands to show the file in the next branch, with an arrow. When I click that, it shows the file in the main branch.

Comment: Nope. all the original history for each files seems to have been lost during the move process.

Comment: Sorry, I have never seen that happen. You must have used some very strange sequence of steps. For instance, did you move the files outside of TFS? Did you use a local workspace? Which version of TFS/Visual Studio did you use?

Comment: I ask because I think you'll find there's no way to get history back. You have done something to cause those files to not be the same files at all. Maybe by learning what you did wrong, you can do the correct steps over again.

Comment: TFS online. I moved the files, got latest and checked in pending changes as I used to

Comment: I did a rollback and went through the same steps to create my branches. However, I see the same issue again. So I have documented the steps above. It seems the truncating of the history log happens when I execute a MOVE

Comment: I strongly suggest you read and understand the [ALM Rangers' Version Control guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/), formerly known as the Branching and Merging Guide.